# Swift Pull to Refresh with UIViewController without TableView or TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

Is it possible to add a pull to refresh in a normal UIViewController that does not have a tableview or tableviewcontroller? I want the functionality to repopulate some fields that I have in my view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a UIScrollView or UICollectionView? In both of those cases you can add `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods, specifically `scrollViewDidScroll` to your delegate and there begin your update when you want to.

If you are not using a scroll view, you could use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your own. You can e.g. use `UIScrollView` for this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this custom control (https://github.com/spbvasilenko/VASRefreshControl) it can be used with a scroll view.you will need to put your view in scroll view. hope it helps